# SSL Certificate not trusted on IE

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, internet-explorer

We have recently replaced the SSL certificate on a web site with a GeoTrust certificate. We didn't realize at first that there was an Intermediate certificate involved, and we were alerted to this by a customer on IE7 or IE8 that got a "not trusted" error. We quickly remedied that by installing the Intermediate cert on the web server, however the customer is still getting the error, much to our dismay.

We have tested SSL on the site here: http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and it passed ok. We have manually tested on IE8, Firefox and Chrome and all work fine, no error.

The customer getting the error is in a government department - is it possible some group policy setting is at work?

The web server is Win2003 (IIS6).

Comment: It's possible their root certificates haven't been updated in a long time. GPO is a remote possibility, but I doubt that's the case (specifically if most website with SSL work).

Comment: Yes it appears that is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have the user try clearing their cache, and checking the list of approved SAs in their copy of IE8. Geotrust may not have their signing cert in that list. I wouldn't be too surprised if it was removed by the gov IT. If that is the case, it may be cheaper for the company to have a pre-approved company sign the cert, rather than try to get the SA approved by the government's IT.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar issue with the browser caching the certificate. Have they tried restarting the browser and/or doing a shift+F5 refresh?